# How to get country code (not ISO code) in Qt

Tags: qt, country-codes

I'm developing an application for Windows. I find a way to get country code like 1(USA) and 82(South Korea).

Comment: I think the only country codes Qt has as built in are  ISO 3166 country codes, see QLocale class

Comment: With county code you mean the phone prefix? That week most probably require a mapping not part of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

`Qt` provides the [`QLocale::Country enum`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#Country-enum) which includes all countries. You can use the [`countryToString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#countryToString) static method in order to get the name of each country.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But, I want to get "Country Codes" not country name . "County codes" means international call number like +1, +82, +86 and so on.